# Hacker rank problem - code optimisation and debugging logical errors required to pass all the test cases for the below python program

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, set

This problem is regarding sets, here is an array arr of integers. There are also disjoint sets, A and B, each containing integers. You like all the integers in the set A and dislike all the integers in set B. Your initial happiness is 0. For each integer in the array, if i belongs to A, you add 1 to your happiness. If i belongs to B, you add -1 to your happiness. Otherwise, your happiness does not change. Output your final happiness at the end.

Note: A and B are set, they have no repeated elements. However, the array might contain duplicate elements.

In the below code, I have tried to take input n,m

```
k = list(map(str,input().split(' ')))
n,m =k

arr=[]
arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
arr1 = list( dict.fromkeys(arr) )
A=set(int(i) for i in input().split())
B=set(int(i) for i in input().split())

a=len(set(arr1).intersection(A))
b=len(set(arr1).intersection(B))
print(a-b)
```

Input Format

The first line contains integers n and m and separated by a space.
The second line contains n integers, the elements of the array.
The third and fourth lines contain m integers, A, and B, respectively.

```
Input 
**1**                **2**
3 2                 13 4
1 5 3               1 7 8 5 3 7 9 4 9 8 2 1 4
3 1                 1 5 3 9
5 7                 7 4 2 8
Output             
1                   0
```

The above piece of code works for small input test cases but it results as the Wrong answer for the rest.
[Follow the link for the actual problem statement](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/no-idea/problem?utm_campaign=social-buttons&utm_medium=linkedin&utm_source=challenge)

This is the code I used but it was unable to clear most test cases. Need help.

Comment: Your logic is incorrect because the input array may have duplicate elements, so you can’t treat it as a set. Re-read the problem statement carefully.

Comment: @PaulR I tried to convert the array to the dictionary using the List items as keys. This will automatically remove any duplicates because dictionaries cannot have duplicate keys.
`k = list(map(str,input().split(' ')))
n,m =k

arr=[]
arr = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
arr = list( dict.fromkeys(arr) )
A=set(int(i) for i in input().split())
B=set(int(i) for i in input().split())

a=len(set(arr).intersection(A))
b=len(set(arr).intersection(B))
print(a-b)`
 still the problem persists. I will be glad if you try running this code against all the test cases.

Comment: Stop coding for a while and start thinking - work through an example with duplicates by hand (on paper) and then the solution should be obvious.

Comment: @PaulR thanks for the advice but I can only work for smaller test cases but passing the larger test cases is the challenge in competitive programming.